# Trying to see if there is a better way to rebuild objects

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, multidimensional-array, hashtable

The only way I know to do this is to add a lot of code to build a custom object to place my values in and pass around.  I was hoping for a more efficient way and looking for suggestions.

There is 2 parts I am trying to figure out:
Logic is the same as below, just different commands.

1. Object A  -  returns multiple results into it self say from
   `Get-ADUser -resultsize 10` command.
   1a. To Complete Part 1, in a foreach loop of Object A. I want to:  `$MyObjA += Object A` (Individual) from the foreach loop.
2. to add to the complexity (Maybe)
   2a. I want (Object A) from `Get-ADUser` to left Join on the output of (Object B) `Get-Mailbox` Combining all it's properties to and in duplication of Object A. So the records will show Object A and Object B.

Now I only used `Get-ADUser` and `Get-Mailbox` in the above questioning because these are commands everyone knows. That being said if I were using those commands what I am trying to do I would not need to. So Please guide me in knowing the best way to handle the objects the way I want to handle them.

The Real issue below is working with UDM Pro by https://enoten.com/.

Their objects are not as friendly as I would like but it is all there. My Ultimate goal is to build functions to break down the website unill the functions can tell me the available numbers and who is assigned a number.  I am half way there.  I am really hoping I do not have to build a custom object or at least the way I know how.
Each function builds off the previous functions.
My Current problem is in `Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_withAvailableNumbers` Procedure where I am trying to do `CustomObject += Object A` where `object A` is the individual object of a group. I am trying to build a new group of the same object.

```
Function Get-UDMLocationNumberBlock_ID
{
    Param ($SiteCode)
    $Return = ''
    #Get-UdmLocation | Where {$_.name -like '*012a*'}
    #$Location = Get-UdmLocation | Where {$_.name -like "*$Sitecode*"}

    $Location = Get-UdmLocation | Where {$_.code -like "*$Sitecode*"}
    $Return = $Location.id

    Return $Return
}
Function Get-UDMLocationNumberBlock_NAME
{
    Param ($SiteCode)
    $Return = ''
    #Get-UdmLocation | Where {$_.name -like '*012a*'}
    $Location = Get-UdmLocation | Where {$_.name -like "*$Sitecode*"}

    #$Location = Get-UdmLocation | Where {$_.code -like "*$Sitecode*"}
    $Return = $Location.Name

    Return $Return
}
Function Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_byName
{
    Param ($SiteCode)

    $Return = ''
    $Return = Get-UdmRmNumberBlock | where {$_.rangeName -like "*$Sitecode*"}

    Return $Return
}
Function Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_byBlockNumber
{
    Param ($DIDBlockNumber)

    $Return = ''
    $Return = Get-UdmRmNumberBlock | where {$_.phoneNumber -like "*$DIDBlockNumber*"}

    Return $Return
}
Function Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_withAvailableNumbers
{
    Param ($SiteCode)
    $DIDBlocks = Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_byName -SiteCode $SiteCode
    $AvailDIDBlocks = ''

    foreach ($DIDBlock in $DIDBlocks)
    {
        if ($DIDBlock.usedQuantity -ne $DIDBlock.Quantity)
        {
                $AvailDIDBlocks += $DIDBlock
        }
    }
    Return $AvailDIDBlocks
}
Function Get-UDMRangesNumbers_bySite
{
    param ($Sitecode,[bool] $OnlyDIDBlocksWithAvailableNumbersInThem = $true)

    if ($OnlyDIDBlocksWithAvailableNumbersInThem)
    { #excludes DID where the block of numbers are full
        $AvailDIDBlocks = Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_withAvailableNumbers -SiteCode $Sitecode
    }
    else
    { #includes DID where the block of numbers are full
        $AvailDIDBlocks = Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks -SiteCode $Sitecode
    }

    foreach ($AvailDIDBlock in $AvailDIDBlocks)
    {
        $DIDNumbers = Get-UdmRmNumber | where {$_.phoneNumberBlockId -eq $AvailDIDBlock.id}

        foreach ($DIDNumber in $DIDNumbers)
        {
            $DIDNumbersfromDIDBlocks += $DIDNumber
        }
    }
    Return $DIDNumbersfromDIDBlocks
}
Function Get-UDMRangesNumbers_bySpecificDID
{
    param ($DIDBlockNumber)

    $AvailDIDBlocks = Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_byBlockNumber -DIDBlockNumber $DIDBlockNumber

    foreach ($AvailDIDBlock in $AvailDIDBlocks)
    {
        $DIDNumbers = Get-UdmRmNumber | where {$_.phoneNumberBlockId -eq $AvailDIDBlock.id}

        foreach ($DIDNumber in $DIDNumbers)
        {
            $DIDNumbersfromDIDBlocks += $DIDNumber
        }
        #$DIDNumbersfromDIDBlocks += Get-UdmRmNumber | where {$_.phoneNumberBlockId -eq $AvailDIDBlock.id}
    }
    Return $DIDNumbersfromDIDBlocks
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function created by Stephane van Gulick at http://powershelldistrict.com/how-to-combine-powershell-objects/ might help you.

The basic meat of the function is:

```
Function Combine-Objects {
    Param (
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]$Object1, 
        [Parameter(mandatory=$true)]$Object2
    )
    $arguments = [Pscustomobject]@()
    foreach ( $Property in $Object1.psobject.Properties) {
        $arguments += @{$Property.Name = $Property.value}  
    }
    foreach ( $Property in $Object2.psobject.Properties) {
        $arguments += @{ $Property.Name= $Property.value}
    }
    $Object3 = [Pscustomobject]$arguments
    return $Object3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right you can do something like this.
I start out with a hashmap of numbers, and I end up with an object rebuilt with the numbers processed in some way.

```
@{a=104; b=307; c=10; d=12; e=53}.GetEnumerator() `
| &{
    Process{
        $args[0][$_.Key]="$($_.Value)$(@{1='st';2='nd';3='rd'}[$_.Value] -replace '^$','th')";
    }
    End{$args[0]}
} @{}
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              10th
e                              53rd
d                              12nd
b                              307th
a                              104th
```

So, for your script, I started with `Get-UDMRangesNumbers_bySite` and worked my way out.
It went from 49 down to 32 lines (a *third*), and has a lot less of those huge variable names.

```
#Get-UDMRangesNumbers_bySite
$SiteCode `
| &{
    Param ([bool]$OnlyDIDBlocksWithAvailableNumbersInThem=$true)
    Process {
        if (!$OnlyDIDBlocksWithAvailableNumbersInThem) {
            #you didn't give us code for this
            Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks -SiteCode $_
            return
        }

        #Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_byName
        #you didn't give us code for this one either
        Get-UdmRmNumberBlock `
        | ?{ $_.rangeName -like "*$Sitecode*" } `
        | ?{ $_.usedQuantity -ne $_.Quantity } `
        | &{ #Get-UDMRange_DIDBlocks_withAvailableNumbers
#I'm not sure your function is working, this will output a single string
#you may have meant `@()`, and in that case you can just delete this block entirely
            Begin { $AvailDIDBlocks='' }
            Process { $AvailDIDBlocks += $_ }
            End { $AvailDIDBlocks }
        }
    }
} -OnlyDIDBlocksWithAvailableNumbersInThem=<#?#> `
| %{
    $AvailDIDBlock=$_
    #you didn't give us this function
    Get-UdmRmNumber | ?{$_.phoneNumberBlockId -eq $AvailDIDBlock.id}
} `
| %{
    #this variable didn't exist so I assume the purpose is to add to it from in here
    $DIDNumbersfromDIDBlocks += $DIDNumber
}
```

Streams are really amazing and clean (for it's purpose of scripting). Free returns, free concatenation, free looping, no nesting hell, and an easy to follow "stack" (data goes top-to-bottom; but your functions dive into each other, pop out, dive in).
PowerShell is much more powerfull than people realise, people dont take advantage of all the non-procedural abilities.

Even if you needed to re-use these blocks elsewhere you can pull them out instead of being inline like I've done and make them functions, and still pipe to them just fine.